# Classes in python, how to set an attributes

Tags: python

When I write class in python, most of the time, I am eager to set variables I use, as properties of the object. Is there any rule or general guidelines about which variables should be used as class/instance attribute and which should not?

for example:

```
class simple(object):
    def __init(self):
        a=2
        b=3
        return a*b

class simple(object):
    def __init(self):
        self.a=2
        self.b=3
        return a*b
```

While I completely understand the attributes should be a property of the object. This is simple to understand when the class declaration is simple but as the program goes longer and longer and there are many places where the data exchange between various modules should be done, I get confused on where I should use a/b or self.a/self.b. Is there any guidelines for this?

Comment: Shouldn't those `__init` be `__init__`?

Comment: A rule of thumb I really like is: Use the smallest scope you can get away with. Local variables have a much smaller scope than attributes, hence if you don't have a convincing use case for it being an attribute...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where you use `self.a` you are creating a property, so this can be accessed from outside the class and persists beyond that function. These should be used for storing data about the object.

Where you use `a` it is a local variable, and only lasts while in the scope of that function, so should be used where you are only using it within the function (as in this case).

Note that `__init` is misleading, as it looks like `__init__` - but isn't the constructor. If you intended them to be the constructor, then it makes no sense to return a value (as the new object is what is returned).

Comment: __init__Typo...My question still exists. I have hard time deciding myself when to create/not-create property. I sometime think the same thing can be used outside of the class and tend to use it. I don't have some kind of decisiveness in determining whether to use it as self.a or a. That's my problem.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades As I said in my question, it's pretty much as case of is this only relevant internally? If so, use a local variable, otherwise, make it an attribute. Try to use the smallest scope possible to keep your code clean, and remember that you can always go back and change it, it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        # Introduce all instance variables on __init__
        self.name = name
        self.another = None

    def get_name(self):
        # get_name has access to the `instance` variable 'name'
        return self.name
```

So if you want a variable to be available on more than one method, make
it an `instance` variable.

Notice my comment on introducing all instance vars on `__init__`.
Although the example below is valid python don't do it.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def foo(self):
        self.b = 1 # Whoa, introduced new instance variable
```

Instead initialize all your instance variables on `__init__` and set
them to `None` if no other value is appropriate for them.

Answer (score 1):

I try to imagine what I want the API of my class to look like prior to implementing it.  I think to myself, If I didn't write this class, would I want to read the documentation about what this particular variable does?  If reading that documentation would simply waste my time, then it should probably be a local variable.

Occasionally, you need to preserve some information, but you wouldn't necessarily want that to be part of the API, which is when you use the convention of appending an underscore.  e.g. `self._some_data_that_is_not_part_of_the_api`.

Answer (score 1):

The self parameter refers to the object itself. So if you need to use on of the class attributes outside of the class you would it call it as the name of class instance and the attribute name. I don't think there is any guideline on when to use self, it all depends on your need. When you are building a class you should try to think about what you will use the variables you creating for. If you know for sure that you will need that specific attribute in the program you are importing your class, then add self.